# The where clause here does not work due the orderBy, is there a work around to this?

Tags: pyspark

The `where` clause here does not work due the `orderBy`. Is there a work around to this?

```python
new_subs_df = new_subs_df.withColumn(
    'last_x_date', 
    lag(col("x_date").over(
        Window.partitionBy('user_id')\
       .orderBy(
           to_date(col('z_date'),None).asc(),
           to_date(col('y_date'),None).asc()
        )\
        .where(col('event_type') != '1')
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

w = Window.partitionBy('user_id').orderBy('z_date','y_date')

new_subs_df = new_subs_df.filter(new_subs_df.event_type != '1').select('user_id',
    F.lag("x_date").over(w).alias("last_x_date"))